# CSS Desktop vs Mobile keeping the background image visible

Tags: html, css

I have the following website:

[www.thewhozoo.com](http://www.thewhozoo.com)

When viewed from a screen with a width of more than 1240px, it displays the images side by side. With a screen below 1240px (e.g. mobile phone), it displays the images beneath each other. This is achieved using:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
```

This all works fine.

My problem however is with the background image:

```
.top-container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: linear-gradient( rgba(0,0,0,0.1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) ),url('../images/background1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
       -webkit-background-size: cover;
       -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
       background-size: cover;
  }
```

When the browser is wide enough (e.g. 930px here), it displays:

[image]

But with a narrower browser (e.g. 480px here) or a mobile device, it displays:

[image]

As you can see, in the image, the background work "WORK" gets chopped off in the second screen.

**Question**

Is it possible in css, to set a minimum width, so that the word "WORK" will always be visible, no matter the size of the browser?

This will give smaller browsers the effect as if they are viewing the page from further away (zoomed out).

Thank you.

Comment: i think a css to the div of the background image `min-width` exists, though i'm not sure... What have you tried?

Comment: @RandomDeveloper Nope, no such property for a background

Comment: We can't parse a whole site, so please add a minimal working code snippet.

Comment: you want the website to be wider than the device, so the user has to scroll horizontally just to see the word "work" Or you always want "work" visible in the viewport without scrolling? I don't think you can make "work" visible without leaving a bunch of space around the image http://i.imgur.com/lN20VxF.png

Comment: Your background image is too big. You can either attach another backgound image according to your window with OR you can create a smaller image that fits on mobile and play around with the background positioning.

Comment: Rememeber the last thing you want is to stratch the image

Comment: Drop "fixed" from your background style. Then add a height using "vw", ie 120vw and play around with it. You'll have to restyle a bit, but won't require drastic changes. Smaller image would help between breakpoints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `background-size: cover` setting makes sure the whole element is always filled by the background images. In your case, the mobile version displays the complete height of the image and centers it horizontally, this way cutting something off at the left and right. If you would display it smaller (which would be necessary to see the whole word "work"), the height would shrink too, and the image wouldn't fill the window anymore.

You can try `background-size: contain` instead, which will always display the whole image, but will leave empty space on either top and bottom or left and right, depending on the orientation. But combined with a background color, this might be something you can live with.

Comment: Thank you. `contain` works. I just need to resize the image for smaller screens.

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-size: 100% 100%`, or `background-size: 100%`

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is make two copies of the background image, when the browser is resized to the minimum width you can use javascript(jquery) to swap the background image from large to small version.

Or you can style the background like:

```
background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:contain;
background-position:center;
```